# Detect multiple TextDecorations in RichTectBox selection

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, text-decorations

I'm trying to make a text-editor as a WPF/C# learning project.
I have 3 togglebuttons (underline, overline and strikethrough).
- these can appear in combination, but how do I detect them ?

My selectionChanged eventhandler:

```
private void rt_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool IsTextUnderline = false;
        bool IsTextStrikethrough = false;
        bool IsOverline = false;

        TextRange range = new TextRange(rt.Selection.Start, rt.Selection.End);

        var decor = range.GetPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty);

        if (decor != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
            {
            TextDecorationCollection coll = (TextDecorationCollection)decor;

            IsTextStrikethrough = (coll.Contains(TextDecorations.Strikethrough));
```

But .Contains() expects a TextDecorationCollection as parameter...
- utterly confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was close (just missed the [0] - whatever that means), here's one that works:

```
private void rt_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Object temp = rt.Selection.GetPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty);
    if (temp.ToString() != "{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}") // multivalue, can't handle..?
    {
        TextDecorationCollection decs = (TextDecorationCollection)temp;
        btnUnderl.IsChecked = decs.Contains(TextDecorations.Underline[0]);
        btnStrike.IsChecked = decs.Contains(TextDecorations.Strikethrough[0]);
        btnBaseli.IsChecked = decs.Contains(TextDecorations.Baseline[0]);
        btnOverli.IsChecked = decs.Contains(TextDecorations.OverLine[0]);
    }
}
```